# Using "only" to describe amounts? Is it used correctly here?

Tags: only

Say someone notices there's frost and ice on the road. "Wow, there's ice on the road..." they exclaim. They then look at the temperature reading and see 9 degrees celsius, "...but it's only 9 degrees outside!"

Is that correct usage of the word "only"?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, in context, it is correct usage. In this case the _only_ refers to the fact that the air temperature is not cold enough to produce ice (at least in theory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, "only" on this context means "not at the level implied by the other measurement mentioned." Another example might be "he's taking calculus but he's only fourteen."